# Does pool from multiprocessing module for parallel processing work in Google Cloud Computing (python)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, cloud, celery

I am very new to parallel processing and I want to run a python script that uses parallel processing in a VM from google cloud that has several cores. My question is if utilizing pool from the multiprocessing module is enough or if I should use something like Celery?